# Método para saber si está caído el servidor con Server-Sent Event

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito algún método que me diga si está caído el servidor.

Tengo el siguiente código, por ejemplo:

```
var conexion       = new EventSource(server + 'config.php');
conexion.onmessage = function(e) { alert('Está conectado'); }
conexion.onerror   = function(e) { alert('Está caído.'); }
```

La cuestión es que la alerta que debería de aparecer cuando está caído, aparece cuando el servidor está conectado. Salen las dos alertas, pero la segunda debería salir solo en caso de haber un error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te esta sucediendo es que:

1. Cuando el servidor esta corriendo, se hace la primer llamada, lo que dispara los eventos `onopen` y `onmessage`.
2. La conexión se se cierra, lo que dispara el evento `onerror`.
3. Automáticamente se realiza una "re conexión" (aprox. cada 3 segundos), lo que provoca que vuelva a empezar el ciclo (es decir, volvemos al *paso 1*)

Para validar que el servidor esta caído podrías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Crear una bandera, por ejemplo `isOpen`, para determinar si se pudo establecer la conexión.
2. Suscribirte al evento `onopen` y modificar el valor de la variable `isOpen` a `true`.
3. Suscribirte al evento `onerror` y usar dicha bandera para determinar si:

   - El servidor esta "caído" (nunca se pudo establecer una conexión)
   - O si hubo un error al intentar recibir una respuesta (se estableció un conexiona pero el contenido de la respuesta no tenia el formato esperado)

Así por ejemplo:

```
(function() {
    var source = new EventSource(server + 'config.php');
    var isOpen = false;

    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
    }, false);

    source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
        // Server up
        console.log('El server esta corriendo');
        isOpen = true;
    }, false);

    source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        if (!isOpen && source.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING) {
            // Server down
            console.log('El server esta caido');
        }
        else if (source.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            // Server error
            console.log('Error en el server');
        }
        isOpen = false;
    }, false);
})();
```

Fuente: [Stream Updates with Server-Sent Events](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-reconnection-timeout)

Comment: No, no me ayuda. Incluso hice lo siguiente para comprobar:

conexion.addEventListener('error', function() {
  if (conexion.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
    // Server down
    console.log('El server esta caido');
  }
console.log(conexion.readyState);
}, false);

y me retorna con 0 siempre.

Comment: @OmarAristides, he actualizado mi respuesta.